Merge 2 brother branches via their parent branch without checking in parent in Visual Studio with TFS
Using TFVC for source control, I have a parent branch name QA, 2 branches dev1 and dev2 are below QA.

 dev1[ with changes]
  \
   QA [ don't want to chek-in until all tests have been done ]
  / 
 dev2 [ target branche ]


What is the best way to merge changes of one project from dev1 to dev2 without checking changes in QA.
I think to merge from dev1 to QA, then from QA to dev2 BUT if I don't checkin changes in TFS, I get:

Source Control Merge Wizard
There were no changes to merge.

So do I really need to check in changes in QA, then merge to dev2 and roll back ?
Is there a better way ? With Shelve maybe ? Or Rollback is the best practice in such case ?
Would have it be possible if I were using Git ?

Looking at this article by Terje Sandstrøm, see if the option "Commit changes after merging" is available.
If it is, you do not need to check in the changes to QA to merge them into dev2: you would right-click on dev1 and select Branching and Merging > Merge..., with dev1 as the source branch and QA as the target branch. (Merge Type: Latest Version). Uncheck the Commit changes after merging option.
Once you have resolved any conflicts, merge QA to dev2 in the same way: the changes from dev1 should be now in dev2:  review them and check them in.
When you merge QA to dev2, TFS should use the changes in your workspace, not just the latest checked-in version.
If you were using Git, this would be much simpler. You could directly merge dev1 to dev2.
git switch dev2
git merge dev1

